# How to prevent a certain character being entered into a google docs/spreadsheet cell?

Tags: google-docs

I would like to have a rule on a group of cells on a google spreadsheet which prevents the user from typing a comma into the cell.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click, select data validation, select text, choose does not contain and enter a comma.